# Add auto increment while inserting data

Tags: postgresql, oracle11g, sql-server-2012

I have two tables lets say table1 with id, fname, lname, gender and table2 with fname, lname.

table2 contains some data. I want to select all the data from table2  that has lname as "roy" and insert into table one incrementing value of id. But I don't want to use triggers. Is there anyway to do this.

Comment: `insert into table1 (fname, lname) select fname, lname from table2 where lname = 'roy'`

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Don't tag unrelated RDBMSs.

Comment: actually I have requirement in all the above mentioned databases.

Comment: I need to update ID also along with the insertion of data that is the problem

Comment: Use a sequence to generate the IDs

Answer (score 0):

If you have auto incrementing column `id` then just omit it while performing an insert and let the database get next value from sequence and assign it to a newly inserted record:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (fname, lname)
  SELECT fname, lname
  FROM table2
  WHERE fname = 'roy'
```

If you don't have one, then you should probably create it, or use the last value + 1 (not safe and not recommended).

In different databases creating an auto incrementing column is done differently:

- PostgreSQL has [`SERIAL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL)
- SQL Server has [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775(v=sql.105).aspx)
- Oracle pre 12c [has sequences and triggers and PL/SQL triggers](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/autonumber-and-identity)